# Create posts using markdown?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, markdown

Can I replace the WYSIWYG editor with a markdown editor? If so, what plugin can I use?

Comment: Why Markdown `1`? Is there any special reasoning for that.

Comment: oh, its just personal preference. I am a developer and may blog about code, in the default editor, its harder to add code blocks

Comment: Just as an update to this question, Wordpress now supports Markdown seamlessly with [JetPack](http://blog.kyletraff.com/use-wordpress-markdown-support-write-cleaner-posts-faster/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure about the version of Markdown, but here's some plugins

I use [markdown-for-wordpress-and-bbpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/markdown-for-wordpress-and-bbpress/) to get wordpress to render posts and comments in markdown format.

For editors, I prefer [markdown-quicktags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/markdown-quicktags/).  It has a bunch of auto-complete features, and seems to be the most actively updated markdown editor plugin.  You might also try [wmd-admin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wmd-admin/) for the wmd editor (Same markdown editor as the stackexchange) or [wp-markitup](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-markitup/) (not markdown specific)

Comment: I've been using wp-markitup for years and the 3.3 update of wp appears to have just broke it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Markdown on Save](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/markdown-on-save/), by Mark Jaquith.

> Allows you to compose content in Markdown on a per-item basis. The markdown version is stored separately, so you can deactivate this plugin any time.

Comment: This is a wordpress.org plugin. How about a wordpress.com feature?

Comment: There is no similar feature on wordpress.com.

Comment: Do you know of anything that will convert the WP editor to a Markdown 1?

Answer (score 3):

Not mentioned is WP-Markdown or Markdown on Save Improved.

I did look at Markdown for WordPress and BBPress but apparently it hasn't been updated since 2008 and never went beyond version 1.0.