# Markdown in WordPress 3.2?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, markdown

I found the question [Create posts using markdown?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/create-posts-using-markdown) about using Markdown on WordPress, however the plugins referred to haven't all been upgraded to WordPress 3.0 or higher.

Since I happen to be a bit pedantic about using updated plugin, what options are available to integrate Markdown for both editing and displaying on a WordPress 3.0 or higher setup?

Answer (score 3):

What about [Markdown on Save](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/markdown-on-save/) by WordPress lead dev [Mark Jaquith](http://profiles.wordpress.org/users/markjaquith/)?

> Allows you to compose content in Markdown on a per-item basis. The
>   markdown version is stored separately, so you can deactivate this
>   plugin any time.

Compatible up to 3.3 attow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is three years later updated answer, for others landing here from Google (like I did once):

[Markdown on Save](http://wordpress.org/plugins/markdown-on-save/) plugin, mentioned in *Michal Mau*'s answers wasn't updated and supported for certain period of time. Now, it seems back on line. In the mean time, it has got a twin plugin, called [Markdown on Save Improved]([Markdown on Save Improved](http://wordpress.org/plugins/markdown-on-save-improved/)), which offers more options.

However, [this twin-plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/markdown-on-save-improved/) is no longer supported, in favor of [Markdown module for Jetpack](http://jetpack.me/support/markdown/). So, if you're starting your yourney with Markdown today (middle of 2014), you should first interest yourself in [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me/), which -- aside of Markdown -- will bring a lot of Wordpress.com goodies to your self-hosted blog.

Note, that [Markdown on Save](http://wordpress.org/plugins/markdown-on-save/) and [Markdown on Save Improved](http://wordpress.org/plugins/markdown-on-save-improved/) extensions are often used with [Markdown QuickTags](https://wordpress.org/plugins/markdown-quicktags/) extension, which gives user an abillity to use keyboard shortcuts, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> for outlining selected text with `* *` and thus making it written in cursive or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> for surrounding it with `** **` and this making it bold.

Jetpack's Markdown module comes with a handy toolbar that replaces non-visual editor default toolbar with buttons corresponding to Markdown. However, at least in current version (Jetpack 3.0) it hasn't got any support for keyboard shortcut. So, if you prefer (as [Markdown QuickTags](https://wordpress.org/plugins/markdown-quicktags/)'s tagline says: "*less clicking, more writing*"), you need to fall back to Markdown QuickTags even though this extension wasn't updated for over two years and seems to be abandoned.

Comment: Small hint, how it @trejder write. The MD Improved plugin is deprecated and was included in Jetpack. but if you like also a small solution, not a the big Jetpack, then use only the MD plugin inside Jetpack, to finde here http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/jetpack/trunk/modules/markdown/easy-markdown.php

Comment: @bueltge Thanks for the direct link. Have you tested that Jetpack snippet freestanding? I see a lot of calls to Jetpack in the code.

Comment: No, I haven't tested this code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Sadly, I can't help you with up-to-date plugins as WordPress went on a Markdown plugin massacre spree in 2019. The intent appears to be to leave the Markdown module in Jetpack as the only working solution in the plugin repository.

The solution I am using with both WordPress 4.9.x and 5.8.x is Robin Adrianse's [Parsedown for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/parsedown-wp/). It converts all posts and comments to HTML on display. It's a bit tricky for very complex posts as all posts are parsed as Markdown first (HTML is still parsed as HTML is part of Markdown spec) but for comments it works without any issues. Either Markdown or HTML comments are supported, transparently. Nothing is permanently converted. Whatever you type in is converted to HTML on display.

I recommend switching to plain text editor to avoid any cross-conversion/parsing issues with the TinyMCE editor or more specifically WordPress's own reparsing of text. There are no performance issues I can see if one is using a caching plugin (who the heck isn't in 2021).

I specify Robin Adrianse's version of Parsedown as there are several other versions which go too far, converting HTML to Markdown permanently. Parsedown supports footnotes among other advanced features. It's a fantastic flexible and powerful flavour of Markdown.